# how to set the same UI display in device and emulator?In my application UI varying device and emulator

Tags: android

Am developed one application .The UI get varying differently in emulator and device.the correct ui displayed in emulator but in device the button size, spinner size,text view all changing deterrently in device.So i have to change some modification in xml file according to the device visibility. any one help me How can i fixed the same xml for device and emulator which  both UI display  cannot change.what are the things i have to include in my project  to fix the same display for emulator and device.

Thanks,

Comment: Sounds like your layout is using absolute values. You need to realize that there are dozens of different screen sizes and densities out there. Your app needs to work fine on all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your Android app to look the same on your device and on your emulator than you have to [define AVD](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/avd.html#creating) with the same characteristics as your device (screen resolution, screen density).